# ExtJs button focus

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, internet-explorer-8, focus

I have a ExtJs form with text fields and buttons. When i use tab keys to focus the elements in the form, the cursor moves to next fields and when it comes to buttons, the focus is not visible in IE8. For users this will be a misleading as focus not visible over buttons. In firefox focus is visible over buttons. Is there any special reason why this happens in IE8 alone?

i am using ExtJs 3.3.4.

Please help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, we need to override the extjs css for button on focus as below,

```
.x-btn BUTTON:focus { 
  outline: thin dotted invert;
}
```

This is show an rectangular dotted line over the button in IE and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

works like a charm in IE and FF, but for some reason outline property does not show using Chrome, no problem using your solution with other css property as border.